# jQuery Validation commas and points

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to extend jQuery validation script for my purposes and I still I haven't had any succes in it. I have utils.js where I create 2 new functions

```
function createValidatorForForm(id) {
var formValidator = $(id).validate({
    errorClass:'help-inline',
    errorElement:'p',

    highlight:function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element.parentNode.parentNode).addClass('error')
    },
    unhighlight:function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element.parentNode.parentNode).removeClass('error')
    }
});
return formValidator;}

function extendJQueryValidator() {
$.validator.addMethod("validNumber", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?|\.\d\d)$/.test(value);
    }, "Message");}
```

Then I use them in html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
extendJQueryValidator();
createValidatorForForm("#form");
</script>
```

and then i use `class="input-small validNumber required"` for the desired field. But I get a simple number validation. Oh, and yes, I need to get validation for numbers with commas and points both. And it will be very kind of you if you give me advice on how to extend validNumber method so it could delete spaces in the field.

Comment: Are you looking for currency validation?

Comment: No, not only for that. Definite fields have to be validated so they can only contain numbers, points and commas and all spaces should be ignored by them.